# How to send ReactDOMServer.renderToString to a file when building with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I want the benefits of react SSR, but I have a unique situation. I'm using an ecommerce service that doesn't give you access to the root directory or server. However I do have access to html files for different pages. My solution is whenever I build my app, render a react ssr string to each of these page's html files, and then hydrate it with a client-side react script.

My question is how would I generate the react ssr string as a step when building with webpack? Every tutorial I've seen shows a nodejs server rendering the strings dynamically per request, but what if I want to render strings once for specific pages during build? FYI I'm also using react-router.

For example, I want an ssr string for the following pages:

- /
- /products
- /about
- /product/:id